# c++ creating a window in a new thread

Tags: c++, window

I have a basic window program, the problem is when i try to create a window in a new thread after the message loop has already started the window displays for a second and disappears. does anyone no the reason for this? can a window be created in a separate thread?

```
     int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
        {
           ::hInstance =hInstance; // initialize global variables
           ::nCmdShow =nCmdShow; 

            // start thread
            HANDLE threadHandle = startThread(StartUp); 

            MSG msg;
            while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) 
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg); 
            }
            ::CloseHandle(threadHandle);

            return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
        }

        DWORD WINAPI StartUp(LPVOID lpParam) // new thread runs here
        {
             //code to create a new window... 

        }
```

what i figured out so far is that the `GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)` returns false if there are no windows in the current thread that it is in... is there a way to get a round this?

Comment: Just give it a message loop.

Comment: its i created a class called CFrame and the point would be to be able to create a window easily, with out having to deal with the message loop. Like a JFrame class in java

Comment: You can abstract the detail away, but there are different things you can do in a message loop that you have to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetMessage()` does not return FALSE if there are no windows.  It is only looking for messages in the calling thread's message queue.  You are specifying `NULL` for its `hWnd` parameter, so it will not care how messages get queued, whether by `PostMessage()` to a window, or by `PostThreadMessage()` to the thread's ID.

Each thread has its own local message queue and thus requires its own message loop.  You can most certainly create a new window in a worker thread after the main thread has started its message loop.  They are independent of each other.  So whatever problem you are having in the main thread is not related to creating a window in a worker thread.  Something else is going on.

With that said, keep in mind that `GetMessage()` returns a `BOOL`, which is actually an `int`, not a true `bool`.  `GetMessage()` can return one of **3** different return values:

1. **-1** if an error occurs
2. **0** if a `WM_QUIT` message is retrieved
3. **>0** if any other message is retrieved

You are only checking for 0 and != 0, so if `GetMessage()` returns -1 on error, you are treating it as a success instead of a failure.  Even MSDN says not to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx

> Because the return value can be nonzero, zero, or -1, avoid code like this:
>
> ```
> while (GetMessage( lpMsg, hWnd, 0, 0)) ...
> ```
>
> The possibility of a -1 return value means that such code can lead to fatal application errors. Instead, use code like this:
>
> ```
> BOOL bRet;
>
> while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
> { 
>     if (bRet == -1)
>     {
>         // handle the error and possibly exit
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         TranslateMessage(&msg); 
>         DispatchMessage(&msg); 
>     }
> }
> ```